# How to make sure a task is started and safely start it if not?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I get an `IEnumerable<Task> tasks` from somewhere that I do not control. I don't know if the tasks are manually created using `new Task`, `Task.Run`, or if they are a result of an async method call `async Task DoSomethingAsync()`.

If I do `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, I risk hanging indefinitely because maybe one or more of the tasks are not started.

I can't do `tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start())`, because then I will get an InvalidOperationException "Start may not be called on a promise-style task" if it's from an async method call (already started).

I can't do `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => Task.Run(async () => await t)))` because each `t` still does not start just by awaiting it.

I assume the solution has something to do with checking each task's `Status` and `Start()` based on that, but I also assume that it can be tricky because that status could change at any time, right? If this is still the way to go, which statuses would be correct to check and what threading issues should I worry about?

Non working case example:

```
//making an IEnumerable as an example, remember I don't control this part
Task t = new Task( () => Console.WriteLine("started"));
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = new[] {t};

//here I receive the tasks
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);//waits forever because t is not started
```

Working case example:

```
//calls the async function, starting it.
Task t = DoSomethingAsync();
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = new[] {t};

//here I receive the tasks and it will complete because the task is already started
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

async Task DoSomethingAsync() => Console.WriteLine("started");
```

Comment: There's never any good reason to ever create an unstarted task, and *certainly* no reason you should ever expose an unstarted task to any other code.  I would consider any method returning an unstarted task to be buggy.  If it's your code, fix it, if it's someone else's code, tell them that they have a bug and that they need to fix their code.  Any method returning a *mix* of started and unstarted tasks is just evil.  If it's your code, fix it, if it's someone else's code, run away from them and never touch their code again, you can't trust it to work.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => Task.Run(async () => await t)))` is just a long, roundabout, and less efficient way of writing `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`  There's no reason to ever write the former unless your CPU is too cold and you have some need to heat it up.

Comment: @Servy great points all over, I will probably end up simply documenting that it expects started tasks and not try to handle unstarted ones.

Comment: There's no reason to even document it, really.  Any code you ever write or interact with anywhere will only expect started tasks, and will never try to start tasks.  It's implicit anytime you're dealing with the TPL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If for whatever reason you cannot change the code to not return unstarted tasks, you can check `Status` and start task if it has `Created` status:

```
if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
   task.Start();
```

All other task statues indicate that task is either completed, running, or being scheduled, so you don't need to start tasks in that statuses.

Of course in theory this introduces race condition, because task can be started right between your check and `Start` call, but, as correctly pointed by Servy in comments - if there ever is race condition here - that means another party (which created that task) is *also* trying to start it. Even if you handle exception (`InvalidOperationException`) - another party is unlikely to do that, and so will get exception while trying to start their own task. So only one side (either you, or code that created that task) should be trying to start it.

That said - much better than doing this is to ensure you might never get unstarted task in the first place, because it's just bad design to return such tasks to external code, at least without explicitly indicating that (while it's for some use cases ok to use unstarted task internally).

Comment: If you're worried about a race condition with someone else starting it, then that means that *someone else is also trying to start the task*, and either they *shouldn't* be trying to start it, and you need to fix that, or *you* shouldn't be trying to start it, because someone else is starting it.